# Data Validation Lists in SAS ODS tagsets.excelxp / proc report / proc template

Tags: sas, sas-ods, proc-report

Am hoping that someone might point me in the right direction.

I am creating a spreadsheet using some elements of proc template and outputting it with a proc report within an ods tagsets.excelxp. This spreadsheet will be sent out in order to collect some data. I would like to limited the data collection entries to Yes or No.

Is it possible to create a data validation list just like Excel as per the image below (a drop down menu with limited values)?

[image]

I have checked the ods tagsets.excelxp options but nothing points to this.
Would I need to create this using Proc Template? If so, is there any code I could look at ?

Thanks

Rbrt

Comment: Last time I checked this wasn't possible :( https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/ods-tagsets-excelxp-and-creating-combo-boxes/m-p/81904/highlight/true#M8979

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TAGSETS.EXCELXP` does not support data validation directly, as far as I know; see for example [this question](https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/ods-tagsets-excelxp-and-creating-combo-boxes/td-p/81904) over on SAS Communities.

Chevelle Parker's paper for SUGI 28, [Generating Custom Excel Spreadsheets Using ODS](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi28/012-28.pdf), provides a way to do it - but not using `tagsets.excelxp`, rather by writing a new tagset.  I don't know why this option wasn't included in `tagsets.excelxp`; perhaps it has some issues, or the method shown here isn't consistent with how `tagsets.excelxp` was written.  It might be worth considering customizing `tagsets.excelxp` to include this, though if that's your first tagset it's a very difficult one to wrap your head around as it has a lot of parts.

Comment: Thanks for the paper Joe. Unfortunately I wasn't able to create this in SAS as this it is a bit complex for me at this stage. I had to do it "manually" in excel due to timelines. AS soon as I am able to create these data validation lists programatically, I will post it on StackOverflow for all to use/edit/perfect.